# Where is the core data located in ios(9.3)?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-simulator

I saw many answers, but in my case, I don't have the below folders mentioned by others.

- library/application support/**iphone simulator**
- library/**developer**
- users/my name/**library**

Who knows where the core data of iphone 6 simulator located?

Comment: It will be in your app's sandbox somewhere. Log that folder when your app starts up.

Comment: I setup to show all apple files, then I can see Developer/CoreSimulator folder, tried to search my project's sqlite, but this file doesn't exist even my app runs on a simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by printing sqlite path. Thanks Rmaddy!